# Magento: how to add a static block AFTER product list

Tags: magento, static-block

In a web site my boss wants me to insert a static block AFTER the product list of that category. Up to now, using the Magento front end application, the one you can see [here](http://bradfrost.com/blog/web/magento-static-blocks/), I have seen that I can add a static block only before the product list. How can I do to put the block after the product list for each category? 
For example [this](http://collaudo.casaarredostudio.it/tavoli-consolle-allungabili.html) is a page of the site I am working on and I would like to display the block at the bottom of the page, after the product list but before the footer links.
I think I should change some files (like page.xml or local.xml) ma I don't know how and I haven't found anything useful in the net. Can you help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your **local.xml** add the following, replacing cms_extra with the identifier of your CMS block.

```
 <!-- Catalog Category (Anchor) -->
 <catalog_category_layered>
     <reference name="content">
         <block type="cms/block" name="cms_extra" after="category.products">
             <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>cms_extra</block_id></action>
         </block>       
     </reference>
 </catalog_category_layered>

 <!-- Catalog Category (Non-Anchor) -->
 <catalog_category_default>
     <reference name="content">
         <block type="cms/block" name="cms_extra" after="category.products">
             <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>cms_extra</block_id></action>
         </block>
     </reference>
 </catalog_category_default>
```

Alternatively if it needs to be a different CMS block on each category, add the following near the bottom of your **catalog/product/list.phtml**..

```
 <?php
     $catcode = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
     echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('category_block_' . $catcode .'')->toHtml(); 
 ?>
```

Create each category's CMS block with identifier of **category_block_*categoryid***

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test this tomorrow as soon as possible when I have obtained the ftp data access to the site. Would you pleade explain me the difference between anchor and not-anchor?

Comment: explanation here: http://www.magedevelopers.com/blog/magento-tutorials/what-is-anchor/  I've edited answer to provide a dynamic option too.